# Cannot assignt to literal

Tags: python, list, append

In  my code i want to create simply the `tsne_results` list which will contain `[tsne_results_50,tsne_results_30,tsne_results_50,tsne_results_100]`.
But i cannot since it says `Cannot assign to literal`. How can i fix it?

```
perplexity_values=[5,30,50,100]
tsne_results=[]

for value in perplexity_values: 
  tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1, perplexity=value, n_iter=250)
  f'tsne_results_{(str(value))}' = tsne.fit_transform(X)
  f'tsne_results_{(str(value))}'.append(tsne_results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables cannot be created dynamically in Python.  You see to want to assign a value to a string, and think that that will create a variable.

It looks you're trying to do something like:

```
tsne_results = {}
for value in perplexity_values:
     ....
     tsne_results[value] = tsne.fit_transform(X)
```